# How can I stop my dwarves from throwing tantrums?

Tags: dwarf-fortress

I've got a handful of dwarfs that won't stop throwing tantrums, breaking things, going insane, and spreading their malcontentness. I killed the first few in an attempt to put an end to their madness, but I'm thinking that escalated the problem. What can I do to get them back to being contributors to dwarven society?

Comment: Boy, if that don't sound like a modern gov't... I might have to look into this game after all lol

Comment: Time to get a prison going.

Comment: @tzenes that'll make a difference?

Comment: if you have police... actually let me write you a serious answer.

Comment: you could always buy them ponies.  That's how I stop my daughter from throwing tantrums.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The short answer is you need a justice system.

> A jail is a room used by the justice
> system within your dwarven community,
> also known as a prison. They are
> designated from a constructed
> restraint, by querying the restraint,
> designating it as a room, and then
> setting it to be used for justice.

Source: https://dwarffortresswiki.org/index.php/Prison#ixzz0v0zfmSU0

The jail is only one part of the equation, you'll also need a Sheriff or Fortress Guard to actually carry out the policing.

Policing your dwarves will cause them to get locked up when they do bad things.  This is an alternative to killing them as that can lead to [bad thoughts](https://dwarffortresswiki.org/index.php/DF2010:Thought#Unhappy_Thoughts) amongst other dwarves.  Its important to note that if your prison isn't nice enough, it can also lead to bad thoughts and make things worse instead of better.

They're going to need a Bed, Food and Alcohol to stay alive.  The better the quality the better for the dwarf.  A table and chair also go a long way.  Finally, the quality of the restraint also affects the mood of the dwarf in question.

Its important that you always have room in your prison for new dwarves.  If you don't, illegal activities will be punished by the hammerer which can lead to bad thoughts and death.

Comment: Got to love how those dwarves get excited about their shiny steel high quality chains.

Comment: @CRoss or how ash is a firesafe material. That's the problem with designing your world from the top down instead of the bottom up.

Comment: Makes for a good game though.

Comment: @CRoss can't argue with that.

Comment: One major downside of having a hammerer or a jail is that nobles will regularly order him to imprison and/or murder your best craftsdorfs because they didn't make that crystal glass encrusted fire imp leather bracelet they really wanted. Consult [your friendly local building safety inspector](http://df.magmawiki.com/index.php/DF2010:Unfortunate_accident) for advice in how to best deal with nobles.

Answer (score 12):

Make a giant engraved dining hall. It is the Final Solution to all happiness problems. Seriously. I heard of a guy who had dwarves who starved to death, but were ecstatic because their dining room was so awesome.

Comment: Have an engraver smooth floors until he becomes legendary, THEN engrave the dining hall. Put a waterfall into your luxurious meeting hall so that everyone sees it. Drain the water through some grates, then pump it back up with a dwarven water reactor. Other things that make dwarves happy, are high value furniture, masterwork quality or any artifacts they happened to make. Examples are gold statues, wells made from masterwork components, beds, tables and chairs, high quality prepared dishes, doors, clothes or armor, weapons, minecarts that are not on a collision course, etc.. you get the idea.

Answer (score 1):

You need to be careful with the killings, because they can lead to feuds, more tantrums and loads of fun™.